# Excel 365 spin button increase/decrease bug

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, scrolling, microsoft, bug

When using a spin button in Excel 365 to increase or decrease the value of a cell by clicking up or down, the value always increases if the spreadsheet is aligned with split rows. This issue appeared once smooth scrolling was implemented and rows could be visually split instead of scrolling entire rows. Microsoft has verified this issue as a bug in case 34137940. However, Microsoft requested that I post here.

While searching the internet, I have found multiple users experiencing the same problem, but no one has found a solution.

### To recreate the problem follow these steps.

1. Under the tab **Development** click **Insert** and select **Spin button** under **Form control**
2. Right click the button and select **Format Control**
3. Under the tab **Control** click the arrown on the option **Cell link** and select a cell you want to increase/decrease the value in
4. Hit **OK**
5. Make a row in the sheet bigger and scroll until that row is split visually on screen.
6. Now, no matter if you click the up or down arrow, the value will increase

I am eager to find a solution for this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this issue, and I have found that zooming in or out will allow the bug to 'reset' and allow normal interactions.